# Upgrade to JDK 7 in Spring Tool Suite (STS)

Tags: java, eclipse

I use STS, and would like to update one project only to Java 7. Its a project that I have exported from git, and uses the switch(String) statement. Can I change the JRE settings for this project alone to Java 7 in STS while keep the others running in Java 1.6? I am currently seeing the error -

```
 Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are 
 permitted
```

Can someone please throw some light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
project >  right click > java > compiler  > compiler compliance  level > 1.7
```

Comment: Sure. But can I do it for just this one project alone?

Comment: You can, if you want to apply it to whole workspace goto `tools > properties >` and then same way